# Java - Applet - Reading the file hosted in the same directory as applet class

Tags: file, security, permissions, nullpointerexception, applet

My applet has this code snippet (basically reading from the file in the same directory).

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(a_file_name));
```

I am playing with Applets to see how to read file that is hosted on the server (or kept in the same directory as *.class file locally).

1. I chose the java class in Eclipse and selected "Run As Applet". I am able to read the file  (which is kept in the workspace/bin directory). So, it worked fine.
2. I hosted the (*.class file; *.txt file and the *.html) file on a remoter server. Gave complete permission to the URL by adding it to the safe list in "Configure Java". I am able to read the file. So, it worked fine.
3. Then I launched the *.html file locally on my machine (Again, I gave the complete permission to the URL by adding it to the safe list in "Configure Java").And *.html, *.txt file and *.class file are in eclipse workspace project bin directory. However, it is not working. The code below is throwing an exception.

   Scanner input = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(a_file_name));

   Case [1]: There is no such thing as safe URL because I am launching from Eclipse (Run as Applet)
   Case [2]: The safe URL starts with http://
   Case [3]: The safe URL starts with file:///D:/apps/eclipse/workspace/AppletSnippet/bin/index.html

Can you throw some light on why it is not working in Case [3]?

By the way, here is the exception I am getting in case of [3]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at AppletSnippet.readFromTextFile(AppletSnippet.java:46)
    at AppletSnippet.init(AppletSnippet.java:100)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: *"Can you throw some light on why it is not working in Case [3]?"* Because it is throwing an exception.  Speaking of which, ***always copy/paste error or exception output.***

Comment: Don't put a stack trace in comments where it is unreadable, edit it into the question (and use code formatting).

Answer (score 0):

OK. The problem is solved.

I just have one single *.class and a text file it is reading *.txt.

Case 1 (Running from Eclipse as an Applet) and Case 2 (Running from Remote Server) -- these options do NOT have any issue with it.

However, in Case 3, if I were running it locally by opening the HTML file,  getClass().getResourceAsStream(a_file_name) is returning NULL.

So, I created a *.jar file with that *.class and *.txt file; And specified the ARCHIVE attribute in my HTML.
Then Case 3 is also working.

Thanks